# FindWindow don't see ,but winSpy can see IE8 (user32.dll)

Tags: c#, user32, findwindow

I need to find download dialog in IE8, i all ready did this in IE8+ ,and all work 100%,i finded the name and class of window/perent window with Spy++/WinSpy,and get my findow.But in IE8 i get stuck,the download dialog don't have any perents,and it seems to me more easy to find it but no.

Here my winSpy

[image]

[image]

You can see class and window name,but FindWindow returns 0

Here my code:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

 a3 = FindWindow("Button", "&Save");
 a4 = FindWindow("Button", "Save");
 a5 = FindWindow("#32770 (Dialog)", "File Download");
 a6 = FindWindow("#32770 (Dialog)", "0% of telechargement.cgi from www.cic.fr Completed");
```

all they are '0'.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Who to find  this download dialog window?

Comment: The class name is just plain "#32770", the (Dialog) annotation is WinSpy trying to be too helpful.  And "Button" cannot work, FindWindow() only finds top-level windows.  Trying to hack the browser's file download prompt is evil and has lots of counter-measures so that viruses don't take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to Hans Passant i find the misstake :

> The (Dialog) annotation is WinSpy trying to be too helpful

Just need to remove `(Dialog)` from class name `"#32770 (Dialog)"`.

You need the change code to:

```
a5 = FindWindow("#32770", "File Download");
a6 = FindWindow("#32770", "0% of telechargement.cgi from www.cic.fr Completed");
```